# Shell use variable and escape dollar character at the same time

Tags: shell, eof, cat, dollar-sign

How can i use a variable and escape a dollar character at the same time in a shell script using **cat << _*EOF*_**?

The important thing is there is no " or ' character i'm using.

Here is my text to write:

```
cat <<- _EOF_ >> "$serverconfigdir/$siteaddress"
    This is a sample text! Here is my variable below!
    $usethisvariable

    This is another sample text! $escapethisstring show it how it looks bla bla.
_EOF_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` in 2nd occurrence:

```
cat <<- _EOF_ >> "$serverconfigdir/$siteaddress"
    This is a sample text! Here is my variable below!
    $usethisvariable

    This is another sample text! \$escapethisstring show it how it looks bla bla.
_EOF_
```